# Change of reprint inform to the end in the footnotes

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, scrbook, bibliographystyle

I wanted to ask how can I change place of the reprint? Actually, I got:

Vgl. Adolf von Harnack,Die Mission und Ausbreitung des Christentums in den ersten drei Jahrhun-derten, 4th ed., 2 vols. (Leipzig, 1965; repr., Darmstadt, 2018), 8.

I want the reprint information at the end. It shall look like this:

Vgl. Adolf von Harnack,Die Mission und Ausbreitung des Christentums in den ersten drei Jahrhun-derten, 4th ed., 2 vols. (Leipzig, 1965), 8 (repr., Darmstadt, 2018).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Harnack.Mission2,
title = {Die Mission und Ausbreitung des Christentums in den ersten drei Jahrhunderten},
shorttitle ={Mission und Ausbreitung},
volumes = {2},
author = {von Harnack, Adolf},
location = {Leipzig},
date = {1965},
edition = {4},
keywords = {sekundaer},
related = {Harnack.Mission},
relatedtype = {reprint},
}
@book{Harnack.Mission,
  location = {Darmstadt},
  date = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=separate,backend=biber,sblfootnotes=false,ibidpage=true,ibidtracker=true,idemtracker=true,pagetracker=spread,sorting=nyvt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
test\footnote{Vgl. \cite[8]{Harnack.Mission2}.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you sure that you want that? Imho it looks very odd if the postnote (the 8) is moved into the reference.

Comment: yes, it is a common feature in German literature of Humanities.

Comment: Although it may seem strange to many, I would be very grateful for an answer.

Comment: well it is not trivial, a \cite can have more than one key. So if you do \cite[and more]{key1,key2} it is rather unclear where the postnote should end. Are you sure the 8 is meant to be the postnote? it is not something that should be in the bib-file?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. "8" is the page number. I am not sure what do you mean with "key". my footnotes resp. \cite have only one book reference.